# Select few bytes from BLOB and convert them to integer in MySQL

Tags: mysql, blob

I have table with BLOB field that holds 7200 bytes.

```
CREATE TABLE `data` 
(
  `id` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `metric_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `ts` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `values` mediumblob,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

I'm using it to store some values collected every second in one hour to reduce row count in big database. Everything works great in my application that handles my BLOB-s in C#, but I have problem with viewing data in MySQL queries.

For example - I want to select first 2 bytes and display them (in MySQL Workbench) as unsigned integer.

How can I do it?

So far I have tried this:

```
SELECT *, cast(substring(`values`, 1, 2) as INTEGER) FROM gs.data limit 10
```

and this:

```
SELECT *, convert(substring(`values`, 1, 2), INTEGER) FROM gs.data limit 10
```

But it always returns 0.

Comment: Provide table structure with `SHOW CREATE TABLE gs.data` and also provide some example data as ascii table data or provide a sqlfiddle.com.. Also post a ascii table table which results you expect.

Comment: Blob data is hexadecimal so i think you need to use MySQL's function `UNHEX()` -> https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex.

Comment: @RaymondNijland Well, `UNHEX` didn't worked, byt I have tried `HEX` and it worked. `conv(HEX(substring(`values`, 1, 2)), 16, 10)`

Comment: @RaymondNijland You can post this as answer.

Comment: `INTEGER` is not a valid casting data type in MySQL. You probably want `UNSIGNED`

Answer (score 1):

Let's say the column `c1` is `BLOB` type where data is stored as `HEX`.

The following sql will convert `c1` from the `BLOB` type to `INT`.

`select CONV(HEX(c1), 16, 10) from table_name;`